# UINavigationBar height in landscape mode does not appear fully

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I used UINavigationBar and when I change to landscape mode the bar look like this .

[image]

in portrait mode

[image]

Comment: Could you show what it looks like in portrait? Is this bar created in IB or in code? If code, could you post it? Thanks.

Comment: @dfd I added image in portrait mode

Comment: @Sam could you print navigation bar height : `self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)`

Comment: That's very odd. It appears as though it's tucked under the status bar. Did you manually add this nav bar in IB, or did you embed it through the IB menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way and this code for `navigation bar` not `navigation controller` . may be you missing to set **Constraint** or conflict each other

```
   override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)


           var frame: CGRect = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)!

                coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

                    let orient = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation

                    switch orient {
                    case .portrait:

                        frame.size.height = 44
                        frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
                    default:

                        frame.size.height = 32
                        frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
                    }

                }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
                    print("rotation completed")
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = frame
                })

    }
```

Comment: If this works, I'll up vote. I've encountered issues in the past and found workarounds. This is the best one yet.

Comment: I print the hight of navigation bar and it's look like your size , landscape Optional(44.0) , Portrait Optional(32.0) @dfd

Comment: @Sam put debug point is that executed this line `frame.size.height = 32`

Comment: @Sam i updated my answer for last time could you check it please .. if it is not work then sorry i will deleted my answer

Comment: @Sam ok let me check .